# How to let users log in in Chrome and allow automatic sign in in Firefox ? (persistent user session in RAILS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am just wondering how to implement Devise log in system so that once a user logs in in Chrome, he is automatically logged in when he opens Firefox. Is it possible to use Current_sign_in_ip for that ?

Comment: You understand that user may be behind NAT and many computers have the same IP address? (looking from Rails perspective)

Comment: Also, what would be a reason for such functionality?

Comment: Here is my situation: I have a view for exporting .csv from rails after user is signed in. But when I grab the URL of the csv and put it into R (statistical analysis tool), I get a sign up error rather than content of csv.

Comment: I would rather go for some kind of access tokens. Once you get a link it contains such token and you don't need username/password based auth. Check out Devise wiki on Github, there's an example